# HandsonTable what is \9 in css ? build failed with systax error

Tags: handsontable

what is \9 in  css below. is this typo or valid character, Do i need to report or modify webpack to recognize this character

https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/blob/master/dist/handsontable.full.css

line 513:  **bottom: -100%\9**; /* Fix for IE9 to spread the ":before" pseudo element to 100% height of the parent element */

verison 8.4.0

Comment: As I read the spec, that's a "tab" character ("\x09" in C) and in this context should be ignored.  It is legal, although unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using latest css loader in webpack.